# Using custom random number generators with Ruby Array#shuffle/sample

Tags: ruby

When using Array#shuffle, Ruby allows the use of a custom randomizer and even provides class `Random` to utilize it. The following example uses the class with a seed value of 48.

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
array.shuffle(random: Random.new(48))  # => [8,6,3,7,10,9,5,2,4,1]
```

I wrote a small monobit test to see how many times a value appeared first in the shuffled array.

```
deck = (1..10).to_a
counts = Hash.new(0)

rng = Random.new

50000.times do
  counts[deck.shuffle(random: rng).first] += 1
end

1.upto(10) do |card|
  puts "#{card}:\t#{counts[card]}"
end
```

The output looks similar to the following:

```
1:  4942
2:  5100
3:  4938
4:  4960
5:  5024
6:  4992
7:  5184
8:  4930
9:  4916
10: 5014
```

Suppose I want to replace the pseudo-random number generator with a new class. Since Array#shuffle appears to use Random#rand in the above example, it would seem straightforward to implement a new class to act as the RNG for shuffling. Here, I implement a new pseudo-random number generator that actually is just a very simple wrapper around `rand`:

```
deck = (1..10).to_a
counts = Hash.new(0)

class FooRandom
  def rand(max=nil)
    max.nil? ? Kernel::rand : Kernel::rand(max)
  end
end

rng = FooRandom.new

50000.times do
  counts[deck.shuffle(random: rng).first] += 1
end

1.upto(10) do |card|
  puts "#{card}:\t#{counts[card]}"
end
```

This, however, does not operate as expected. `FooRandom#rand` is called, but the shuffling produces the following distribution:

```
1:  0
2:  5423
3:  5562
4:  5544
5:  5512
6:  5569
7:  5535
8:  5595
9:  5524
10: 5736
```

As you can see, the array value 1 never appears in the first position of the array after the array is shuffled. Anyone have an idea why?

Comment: In ruby-1.9.3-p392 I got the expected distribution with both examples.  But in Ruby-2.0.0-p0  I see the same results as you.

Comment: Thank you, Shawn. Yeah, I am using ruby-2.0.0-p0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [bug in Ruby 2.0.0p0](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7935) where the limit is off by one.

This has been fixed in Ruby 2.0.0p195, so you should upgrade your installation.

Comment: Thanks for posting that (and reporting the bug.)  I suspected it might be a bug and was going to look into that today.

Answer (score 2):

In ruby 1.9.3 max is nil.   In Ruby 2.0.0 max is passed to rand.  I was able to get it to work by changing the rand method to the following.

```
class FooRandom
  def rand(max=nil)
    max.nil? ? Kernel::rand : Kernel::rand(max+1)
  end
end
```

It was off by one before.

Here's an excerpt of the C source from 
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-shuffle

```
i = RARRAY_LEN(ary);
ptr = RARRAY_PTR(ary);
while (i) {
    long j = RAND_UPTO(i);
    VALUE tmp;
    tmp = ptr[--i];
    ptr[i] = ptr[j];
    ptr[j] = tmp;
}
return ary;
```

}

Comment: Shawn, that works great! I wonder if the change made to rand from 1.9.3. to 2.0.0 was intentional or perhaps a bug?

Comment: @ThaiDoan: It's a bug, see my answer.