# How many random requests do I need to make to a set of records to get 80% of the records?

Tags: arrays, random, statistics, number-theory

Suppose I have an array of 100_000 records ( this is Ruby code, but any language will do)

```
ary = ['apple','orange','dog','tomato', 12, 17,'cat','tiger' .... ]
results = []
```

I can only make random calls to the array ( I cannot traverse it in any way)

```
results << ary.sample 
# in ruby this will pull a random record from the array, and 
# push into results array
```

How many random calls like that, do I need to make, to get least 80% of records from `ary`. Or expressed another way - what should be the size of `results` so that `results.uniq` will contain around 80_000 records from `ary`.

From my rusty memory of Stats class in college, I think it's needs to be 2*result set size = or around 160_000 requests ( assuming random function is random, and there is no some other underlying issue) .  My testing seems to confirm this.

```
ary = [*1..100_000];
result = [];  
160_000.times{result << ary.sample}; 
result.uniq.size # ~ 80k
```

This is stats, so we are talking about probabilities, not guaranteed results. I just need a reasonable guess.

So the question really, what's the formula to confirm this?

Comment: If you use Fisher-Yates shuffle, you'll need exactly 80K requests

Answer (score 1):

I would just perform a quick simulation study. In R,

```
N = 1e5
# Simulate 300 times
s = replicate(300, sample(x = 1:N, size = 1.7e5, replace = TRUE))
```

Now work out when you hit your target

```
f = function(i) which(i == unique(i)[80000])[1]
stats = apply(s, 2, f)
```

To get

```
summary(stats)
# Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
# 159711  160726  161032  161037  161399  162242
```

So in 300 trials, the maximum number of simulations needed was 162242 with an average number of 161032.

Answer (score 0):

With Fisher-Yates shuffle you could get 80K items from exactly 80K random calls

Have no knowledge of Ruby, but looking at https://gist.github.com/mindplace/3f3a08299651ebf4ab91de3d83254fbc and modifying it

```
def shuffle(array, counter)
  #counter = array.length - 1

  while counter > 0
    # item selected from the unshuffled part of array
    random_index = rand(counter)

    # swap the items at those locations
    array[counter], array[random_index] = array[random_index], array[counter]

    # de-increment counter
    counter -= 1
  end

  array
end

indices = [0, 1, 2, 3, ...] # up to 99999

counter = 80000
shuffle(indices, 80000)

i = 0
while counter > 0
  res[i] = ary[indices[i]]
  counter -= 1
  i += 1
```

UPDATE

Packing sampled indices into custom RNG (bear with me, know nothing about Ruby)

```
class FYRandom
  _indices = indices
  _max     = 80000
  _idx     = 0
  def rand()
    if _idx > _max
      return -1.0
    r = _indices[idx]
    _idx += 1
    return r.to_f / max.to_f
  end
end
```

And code for sample would be

```
rng = FYRandom.new

results << ary.sample(random: rng)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But This only works, if I control the original array or can overwrite how shuffle is implemented.  As I mentioned, I have no control over that. I can only use the result of shuffle, I can't specify the location from where I'm extracting an item. I also can't make a copy of the original array. So I can't say " grab this item at this index, from the unsnuffled part of the array".   I can only make a request, and it randomly returns 1 item from the array. It could possibly even return the same item from the array multiple times ( in fact it wll)

Comment: @konung `if I control the original array or can overwrite how shuffle is implemented. As I mentioned, I have no control over that.` I understand that, so code works on indices only. But you could control RNG, right? So you could do indices first as I suggested and then make index->RN conversion so that internally it will be converted back and return item at index. I know nothing about Ruby, but was referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117548/using-custom-random-number-generators-with-ruby-arrayshuffle-sample